# Android place views under BottomAppBar

Tags: android, coordinator-layout, android-bottomappbar

I want to make a very simple layout. One RecyclerView, one EditText, one BottomAppBar without FloatingActionButton. But I can't understand, how to place my views under the BottomAppBar?

What I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent>

 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     app:layout_anchor="@id/bar"
     app:layout_anchorGravity="top">

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:orientation="vertical">
         <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

         <EditText
             android:id="@+id/editText"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
     </LinearLayout>
 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>   

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:hideOnScroll="true"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/baseline_menu_white_24" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

What I want:
[image: example]
Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe there is any way to set custom behaviour to BottomAppBar?